# Regular expression matching a sequence of consecutive words with spaces except for the last space

Tags: regex

I have a list of words and I want to match any combination of those words. Assume that I have the words `apple`, `orange` and `mango` and I am working with the following string:

```
This place has the best apple pie. They also have orange, apple and mango-apple smoothie ...
```

The regular expression that I have so far is `\b((apple|orange|mango)[\s-(,\s)]*)+`

It matches the right combination of words but additionally it matches an extra space at the end of the sequence. The matches I get:

```
"apple "
"orange, apple "
"mango-apple "
```

I know why it does that. How can I change the regular expression to get rid of that last space at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `\b` at the end seems to have worked for me. Also, the `-` should be put last when placed in square brackets. So, all you need to do is to change your regex to this: `\b((apple|orange|mango)[\s(,\s)-]*)+\b`

EDIT:

As per your comment, I have tried out this: `\b((apple|orange|mango)([\s,-]+(apple|orange|mango))*)+\b`. The problem with your current regex is that you are also throwing in the spaces at the end so that you could match `apple mango` for instance.

The regex I propose should match the spaces, dashes or commas if and only if they are followed by the words `apple`, `orange` or `mango`.

Comment: The \b at the end doesn't work. Note: The ** were used to indicate the matches I wanted. I have removed those to avoid confusion.

Comment: @mbsheikh: I see. I have made some edits. The new regex should fit what you need.