# regex - merge repeated consecutive words preserving last space

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

`{{TAG}} {{TAG}}{{TAG}} {{TAG}} some other text. {{TAG}} {{TAG}}`

and I am trying to merge multiple consecutive occurrences of `{{TAG}}` into one. So I have this regex `re.sub(r'(({{TAG}})\s*)+', "{{TAG}}", text)` which works fine to remove multiple occurrences and gives me this

`{{TAG}}some other text. {{TAG}}`.

But its taking one extra space at the end, which I am trying to avoid. So that I get

`{{TAG}} some other text. {{TAG}}`

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930320/regular-expression-matching-a-sequence-of-consecutive-words-with-spaces-except-f), but that didn't solve my problem. Any suggestions to improve my regex or any other alternative in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way is that instead of `+` you can split the regex into two as

```
>>> re.sub(r'(?:{{TAG}}\s*)*{{TAG}}', r'{{TAG}}', string)
'{{TAG}} some other text. {{TAG}}'
```

- `(?:{{TAG}}\s*)*` Matches zero or more `{{TAG}}` with space at the end.
- `{{TAG}}` Match the last `{{TAG}}` without any space.

---

You can also solve this using a positive look ahead

```
>>> re.sub(r'{{TAG}}\s*(?={{TAG}})', r'', string)
'{{TAG}} some other text. {{TAG}}'
```

- `{{TAG}}\s*` Matches one `{{TAG}}` followed by space.
- `(?={{TAG}}` Positive look ahead. Checks if the `{{TAG}}` matched in the above point is followed by another `{{TAG}}`

Answer (score 1):

You're matching `{{TAG}}\s*` once or more, but you want to match `{{TAG}}` once, followed by zero or more instances of `\s*{{TAG}}`.

```
re.sub('({{TAG}}(?:\s*{{TAG}})*)', '{{TAG}}', text)
```